# Convert Doc to XML

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have make simple program convert doc file to xml file using vb.net.

```
Dim app As Word.Application = New Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document = app.Documents.Open(txtFileName.Text)

Dim writer As New XmlTextWriter("product.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
writer.WriteStartDocument(True)
writer.WriteStartElement("JUDGEMENT")
writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented

For Each paragraph As Word.Paragraph In doc.Paragraphs
    paragraph.Next()
    writer.WriteStartElement("p")

    If (paragraph.Range.Font.Bold) Then
        writer.WriteStartElement("b")
        writer.WriteString(paragraph.Range.Text.Trim)
        writer.WriteString(paragraph.Range.Text)
        writer.WriteEndElement()
    Else
        writer.WriteString(paragraph.Range.Text)
    End If

    writer.WriteEndElement()
Next

writer.WriteEndElement()
writer.WriteEndDocument()
writer.Close()
app.Quit()
```

The result will be something like this.
Problem is bold tag is not at the bold font, it put at the end of sentences.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<JUDGEMENT>
  <p>
    <b>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</b>
  </p>
  <p>
    <b>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</b>
  </p>
</JUDGEMENT>
```

But I need a result like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<JUDGEMENT>
  <p>
    <b>Lorem Ipsum </b>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
  </p>
  <p>
    <b>Lorem Ipsum </b>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
  </p>
</JUDGEMENT>
```

What do I need to add or changes?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: You might consider letting Word do this for you, by calling the Document.SaveAs( xmlFormat ).    Even if the resulting XML isn't what you're looking for, it'll likely be easier to translate XML to XML than Word to XML.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the end tag at the end of the paragraph.  Try it this way:

```
If (paragraph.Range.Font.Bold) Then
    writer.WriteStartElement("b")
    writer.WriteString(paragraph.Range.Text.Trim)
    writer.WriteEndElement() 
    writer.WriteString(paragraph.Range.Text)        
Else
    writer.WriteString(paragraph.Range.Text)
End If
```